# What is the solution to this, Nginx stop when ever I restart it

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

when ever I restart nginx or reboot the VPS nginx and nginx.service stop. and give this error.
sudo systemctl start nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I am using Centos 7.6 with mainline nginx latest version from nginx.org is installed.

[root@host ~]# systemctl status nginx.service
* nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-06-25 18:41:49 UTC; 22min ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 670 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 691 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 692 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           |-692 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
           `-693 nginx: worker process

Jun 25 18:41:49 host systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Jun 25 18:41:49 host systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/nginx.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jun 25 18:41:49 host systemd[1]: Started nginx - high performance web server.
[root@host ~]# systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@host ~]# systemctl status nginx.service
* nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-06-25 19:04:56 UTC; 21s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 858 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 861 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 692 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 25 19:04:56 host systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Jun 25 19:04:56 host nginx[861]: nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33
Jun 25 19:04:56 host systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 25 19:04:56 host systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Jun 25 19:04:56 host systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jun 25 19:04:56 host systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.

Maybe it apache listening on port:80 (httpd). if it is how to remove it and set nginx as default on every boot. 
other than that I have no Idea WHAT is causing this problem. I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy. Any valid solutions will be valuable. 
This is the third time I'm installing Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

There was a configuration error from your message:

Jun 25 19:04:56 host nginx[861]: nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33

It means that on line 33 of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, there shouldn’t have a “server” statement.

How about share your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?

Comment: I deleted All of the installs I will reinstall and give to the file content. as soon as possible.

Comment: I've reinstalled nignx and then manage to create a mainsite.conf file by getting help and cofigured the default.conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d and it is working fine.

Comment: By the problem you pointed out was helpful I needed to create a separate file to enable the server to work.